# Issue with email font size displaying on Windows phone 8

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, html-email

I've had a good trawl trying to find previous questions on this issue but to no avail.
I'got an issue with an email displaying in Windows Phone 8 OS, testing in Litmus. 
It's fine on every other platform.
The Text in a table is tiny. Tried formatting in every way I know with no joy.
It's probably something really obvious I'm missing here!

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" color="#777777" size="2" style="line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 12px">
<b>test<br />
lorem ipsum</b> delores sit annum</font>
<div style="clear: both; height:1px;font-size:1px">&nbsp;</div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; float:left" >
<tr>
  <td style="padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 4px" NOWRAP>
    <font color="#18833f" style="line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 12px" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">table text is tiny<br />
    gdfggdfg</font></td>
  <td style="padding-right: 8px; padding-top:4px" NOWRAP>
    <font color="#999999" style="line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 12px" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">dgdfgdgfdg<span style="display: none">&nbsp;</span> &nbsp;<br />
    gfdgfgdgfdg<font color="#999999">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="clear: both; height:1px;font-size:1px">&nbsp;</div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px" >
<tr>
  <td NOWRAP>
  <p style="display: block"><font color="#999999" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" size="2" style="line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 12px">
  <font color="#18833f"><b>fdgfdgfggdfg</b></font>&nbsp;dfg dfgd fg dfg, U.K. </font></p></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<hr align="left" width="100%" COLOR="#999999" size="1" NOSHADE style="display: block; height: 1px;border: none;margin: .2em 0; padding: 0;background-color:#999999;"/>
<p style="margin-top: 0px">
  <font color="#999999" size="1" style="font-size: 9px; line-height: 1em" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"> fgdfgfgfdg dfg df dfg dfgdf g </font></p>
<style>body, td, p {font-size: 12px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px}</style>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not obvious. For whatever reason, Windows Phone does font sizes in tables like it's '96 – in the `size` attribute. The reason it looks the same in your first NOWRAP td is because you have nested a font tag inside another with `size="2"`, causing it to still be `size="1"`.

Rough guide (attribute only goes up to 7):
`size="1"` = 10-12px
`size="2"` = 13-16px
`size="3"` = 17-20px